# What is a proper idiom in pandas for creating a dataframes from the output of a apply function on a df?

Tags: python, pandas

Edit --- I've made some progress, and discovered the drop_duplicates method in pandas, which saves some custom duplicate removal functions I created.
This changes the question in a couple of ways, b/c it changes my initial requirements.

One of the operations I need to conduct is grabbing the latest feed entries --- the feed urls exist in a column in a data frame. Once I've done the apply I get feed objects back:

```
import pandas as pd
import feedparser
import datetime

df_check_feeds = pd.DataFrame({'account_name':['NYTimes', 'WashPo'],'feed_url':['http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml', 'http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/rss/homepage'], 'last_update':['2015-12-28 23:50:40', '2015-12-28 23:50:40']})
df_check_feeds["feeds_results"] = pd.DataFrame(df_check_feeds.feed_url.apply(lambda feed_url: feedparser.parse(feed_url)))
df_check_feeds["entries"] = df_check_feeds.feeds_results.apply(lambda x: x.entries)
```

So, now I'm stuck with the feed entries in the "entries" column, I'd like to create a two new data frames in one apply method, and concatenate the two frames immediately.

I've expressed the equivalent in a for loop:

```
frames_list = []
for index in df_check_feeds.index:
     df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df_check_feeds.entries[index])
     df_temp['account_name'] = df_check_feeds.ix[index,'account_name']
     # some error checking on the info here
     frames_list.append(df_temp)
df_total_results = pd.concat(frames_list)
df_total_results
```

I realize I could do this in a for loop (and indeed have written that), but I feel there is some better, more succinct pandas idiomatic way of writing this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more compact way could be:

```
df_total_results = df_check_feeds.groupby('account_name').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x['entries'].iloc[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Why does the account end up as the new index  ? (and the integer index end up in the unlabeled column?)

Comment: @12programmerwannabe, For the integer index, it is created with `pd.DataFrame(x['entries'].iloc[0])`, when a dictionary forms the data frame, defaultly np.arange(n) is set a the index. And regarding the `account_name`, it is set as index during the `groupby`. So if you check the index of the final dataframe by using `df.index`, you can see that both the account and integer index are set as the multi-index.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.